# auto layout is stretching image, autolayout, ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am adding the uiimageview to the button in a way that :

1. uiimageview is center along the y-axis ( just edited again )
2. the trailing space of uiimageview is always 10 points from button

and for this purpose, I am doing like the following

```
 // Just added these lines 
    UIImage *img                =   [UIImage imageNamed:@"reload.png"];
    indicator                   =   [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.width)];
    indicator.image             =   img;

    [self.logInButton addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat: @"H:|[indicator]-(10)-|"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(indicator)]];

    [self.logInButton addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.logInButton
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:indicator
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0]];
```

However, what I am getting is that uiimageview is stretching out like below

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas about this. All comments are appreciated at here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraint is saying that the image view should be flush with the left edge and 10 points from the right, so the image will stretch if the button is larger than the size of the image. You either need to center it in the x direction (and eliminate the one to the right side) or set a specific size for the image view.

Comment: I am still confused,just edited the OP, please take a look again.

Comment: @ttran, I don't understand your confusion. Your constraintWithItem code centers it on the y axis, that's vertical, not horizontal. The visual format has it up against the left edge (H:|[indicator] this part) and 10 from the right edge (this part [indicator]-(10)-|). You need to get rid of the visual constraint and add another like your second one, but with CenterX attribute.

Comment: sorry if OP lost you again. my goal is like [this](http://cl.ly/Mwqz). that is why I am using centerY. Like you said, if i remove visual constraint, I wont have an image located 10 from the right edge of a button.

Comment: @ttran, ok it's good that you finally pointed out what it is you're trying to accomplish. I couldn't tell from what you posted, what it was supposed to look like. So, you just want to make the right constraint, and get rid of the left one. Just @"[indicator]-(10)-|"

Comment: thanks rdelmar. what i did for the right constraint was **[indicator]-(10)-|:H** and xcode complained about the syntax. Now i get how to do the right one.